# Problem with custom written compare function

Tags: c, max, declaration, min, function-definition

could someone have a quick look at my code because i just can't find out why i am not getting the result i want. The goal here is to find largest and the smallest number from an array that i gave to my function and if the difference between max and min is larger than 0.001 then i should get one printf statement and if not then another.

would be really grateful for your help.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int alle_gleich(double*, int);
int pruefe_sort(double*, int);
double max_delta(double*, int);
// Vorschlag für Felddeklarationen und Initialisierungen :

int alle_gleich(double* array[], int anz)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (anz < 2)
        return -1;

    double* max = array[0];
    double* min = array[0];
    double summe=0;

    for (i; i < anz; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
        if (array[i] < min)
            min = array[i];
    }

    if ((max - min) > 0.001)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 4;
    double werte_praktisch_gleich[] = { 9.9995, 10.0, 10.0002, 9.99991 };
    double werte_sort_0123[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    double werte_unsortiert[] = { 1, 3, 2, 0 };
    double werte_maxabw_0komma1[] = { 1.0, 1.05, 0.95, 1.01 };
    double werte_identisch;
    
    werte_identisch = alle_gleich(werte_praktisch_gleich, n);
    
    if (alle_gleich(werte_praktisch_gleich, n) == 1)
        printf("Die Werte sind identisch!\n");
    else
        printf("Die Werte sind nicht identisch!\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `alle_gleich()` twice. You assigned the result to a variable, so use `if (werte_identish)`

Comment: @Linas These arrays     double werte_sort_0123[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    double werte_unsortiert[] = { 1, 3, 2, 0 };
    double werte_maxabw_0komma1[] = { 1.0, 1.05, 0.95, 1.01 }; are not used.

Comment: `max` and `min` should not be declared as pointers. You should be getting warnings from those initializations.

Comment: Your forward declaration of `alle_gleich()` matches its usage and seems appropriate for its purpose.  However, the *definition* does not match, and is not appropriate, and your compiler should be complaining to you about that.

Comment: That explains why the initializations aren't getting warnings.

Comment: `double* array[]` should be either `double *array` or `double array[]`, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

For starters these function declarations

```
int alle_gleich(double*, int);
```

and

```
int alle_gleich(double* array[], int anz)
```

do not coincide.

There is no sense to call the function `alle_gleich` twice

```
werte_identisch = alle_gleich(werte_praktisch_gleich, n);

if (alle_gleich(werte_praktisch_gleich, n) == 1)
//...
```

The compiler should issue a message for these declarations

```
double* max = array[0];
double* min = array[0];
```

because there are initialized pointers by doubles.

Also the variable `summe`

```
double summe=0;
```

is not used.

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
int alle_gleich( const double array[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 ) return 0;

    double max = array[0];
    double min = array[0];

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( max < array[i] )
        {
            max = array[i];
        }
        else if ( array[i] < min )
        {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max - min > 0.001;
}
```

And use English words for identifiers. Otherwise your code is unreadable.

Though it is almost always better to write functions that perform only one task. That is you could write a function that finds minimum and maximum elements in an array. And then using this information to compare the minimum and maximum values in another code.

For example define the following function.

```
struct indices_pair
{
    size_t first;
    size_t second;
};

struct indices_pair minmax_element( const double a[], size_t n )
{
    struct indices_pair minmax = { .first = 0, .second = 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( minmax.second < a[i] )
        {
            minmax.second = i;
        }
        else if ( a[i] < minmax.first )
        {
            minmax.first = i;
        }
    }

    return minmax;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
struct indices_pair werte_identisch = minmax_element( werte_praktisch_gleich, n );

if ( werte_identisch.first != werte_identisch.second && werte_identisch.second - werte_identisch.first > 0.001 )
{
    puts( "Die Werte sind identisch!" );
}
else
{
    puts( "Die Werte sind nicht identisch!" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. In `alle_gleich`, the first argument should be `const double *` and *not* `double *array[]`. The latter is equivalent to `double **array`.
2. In `alle_gleich`, `max` and `min` should be just `double` and *not* `double *`.
3. In `main`, no need to call the function *twice*. Just remember the return value and change the `if`.
4. In `main`, there are several unused arrays.
5. `alle_gleich` calculates `min` and `max` *values* but there is no way to return those to a caller. Likewise with `summe`
6. We can return *multiple* values if we create a `struct` to hold them.

---

Here is the code with the errors fixed. It is generalized to return multiple values in a [new] `struct`:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARINGS
#include <stdio.h>

struct minmax {
    double minval;                      // minimum value found
    int minidx;                         // index into array of min value

    double maxval;                      // maximum value found
    int maxidx;                         // index into array of max value

    double summe;                       // sum of array elements
    int ismatch;                        // 1=(min - max) > 0.001
};

int alle_gleich(const double *, int, struct minmax *);
int pruefe_sort(double *, int);
double max_delta(double *, int);

// Vorschlag für Felddeklarationen und Initialisierungen :

int
alle_gleich(const double *array, int anz, struct minmax *ret)
{
    int i = 0;
    double curval;

    if (anz < 1)
        return -1;

    // to simulate the original function, pass a null pointer
    struct minmax noarg;
    if (ret == NULL)
        ret = &noarg;

    curval = array[i];

    ret->minval = curval;
    ret->minidx = i;

    ret->maxval = curval;
    ret->maxidx = i;

    ret->summe = curval;

    for (i = 1;  i < anz;  i++) {
        curval = array[i];

        // calculate the sum
        ret->summe += curval;

        // get minimum value and the corresponding array index
        if (curval < ret->minval) {
            ret->minval = curval;
            ret->minidx = i;
        }

        // get maximum value and the corresponding array index
        if (curval > ret->maxval) {
            ret->maxval = curval;
            ret->maxidx = i;
        }
    }

    // calculate the return value
    ret->ismatch = ((ret->maxval - ret->minval) > 0.001);

    return ret->ismatch;
}

void
dotest(const double *arr,int n,const char *sym)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s:\n",sym);

    struct minmax ret;
    int ismatch = alle_gleich(arr, n, &ret);

    if (ismatch)
        printf("Die Werte sind identisch!\n");
    else
        printf("Die Werte sind nicht identisch!\n");

    printf("Summe is %g\n",ret.summe);
    printf("Min is %g at index %d\n",ret.minval,ret.minidx);
    printf("Max is %g at index %d\n",ret.maxval,ret.maxidx);
}

#define DOTEST(_sym) \
    dotest(_sym,sizeof(_sym) / sizeof(_sym[0]),#_sym)

int
main(void)
{
    double werte_praktisch_gleich[] = { 9.9995, 10.0, 10.0002, 9.99991 };
    double werte_sort_0123[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    double werte_unsortiert[] = { 1, 3, 2, 0 };
    double werte_maxabw_0komma1[] = { 1.0, 1.05, 0.95, 1.01 };

    DOTEST(werte_praktisch_gleich);
    DOTEST(werte_sort_0123);
    DOTEST(werte_unsortiert);
    DOTEST(werte_maxabw_0komma1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
werte_praktisch_gleich:
Die Werte sind nicht identisch!
Summe is 39.9996
Min is 9.9995 at index 0
Max is 10.0002 at index 2

werte_sort_0123:
Die Werte sind identisch!
Summe is 6
Min is 0 at index 0
Max is 3 at index 3

werte_unsortiert:
Die Werte sind identisch!
Summe is 6
Min is 0 at index 3
Max is 3 at index 1

werte_maxabw_0komma1:
Die Werte sind identisch!
Summe is 4.01
Min is 0.95 at index 2
Max is 1.05 at index 1
```