# Dynamic Dispatch in C: is it faster to use function pointers or not?

Tags: c, performance, oop, optimization

Suppose that I need to choose between two functions to call, dynamically (like what we do in a vtable in C++):

common.h

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define TEST_N 100000000

static volatile int state = 0;
static void foo1() {
    state = 1;
} 
static void foo2() {
    state = 2;
}
```

test1.c

```c
#include"common.h"
int foo_choose(){
    if (rand()%2 == 0){
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));
    for(size_t i = 0; i<TEST_N; i++){
        switch(foo_choose()){
            case 1:
                foo1();
                break;
            case 2:
                foo2();
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

test2.c

```c
#include"common.h"
void (*foo_choose(void))(){
    if (rand()%2 == 0){
        return &foo2;
    }
    return &foo1;
}

int main(){
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));
    for(size_t i = 0; i<TEST_N; i++){
        (foo_choose())();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compare the performance. Apparently, on ARM64 apple clang with `-O1` or `-O3`,  `test1` is significantly faster than `test2`. With gcc12 they are about as fast no matter how we set the optimisation level. I have looked at the assembly produced, but haven't discovered anything significant.

Does anyone know why we get the performance difference, and is there any reason why one should be faster in general, **when the code gets much more complicated than the demo above**?

And which is the better way of doing dynamic dispatch in C, `test1` or `test2`? After all, `test1` is way more flexible since it allows processing something which is not a function pointer.

EDIT: If it is too hard to decide, please just share some thoughts on this. If this depends on architecture, surely it is better to write codes that works for all possible architecture at the same time, so is there a good way to do it?

Comment: It depends of a lot of things (platform, compiler, processor, etc.), there is no general advice that can be given here. If you have really time critical code, mesure it. Also depending on what `foo1` and `foo2` do, the difference between the two methods might become insignificant.

Comment: You can take a look at the assembly code to get some clues

Comment: Aside: it's a bad idea to put the function implementations in the header file `common.h`, they should be in `common.c`, with their declarations in `common.h`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have measured it. Don't give a comment without reading the question.

Comment: Having the code in the translation unit (via the header) makes inlining possible which eliminates the runtime-dominating function call. You could try switching on link time or whole program optimization if the TUs are different. After that, the jumps will dominate the timing. I *suppose* that the compiler cannot inline `foo1` and `foo2` in  the function pointer version unless it can prove that it is equivalent to the switch version and simply emit that code.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That is a good point. Which jump are your referring to? Also, I have tried switching off optimisation; in that case there would be no inlining.

Comment: Your measurements look suspicious given that the compilers inline calls to foo1 and foo2 in test1 but not in test2. "I have tried switching off optimisation" It makes a total of zero sense to measure performance with optimisations turned off.

Comment: @MrUser The switch depending on `foo_choose` in test1.c, and the `if` clause in test2.c And yes, as n.m said, non-optimized measurements are pointless.

Comment: @n.m. I don't think you can assume the compiler cannot inline calls in test2.

Comment: @MrUser [gcc 13 doesn't.](https://www.godbolt.org/z/vTdWYWd6M)

Comment: I assume nothing at all, I look at the assembly.

Comment: @MrUser I _have_ read your question, I meant "mesure your _actual_ time critical code". Mesuring your simplified code is not at all the same thing.

Comment: @n.m. You can look at different architectures and different compilers. I did not do the test on x86.

Comment: I like how clang gets rid of the jump in (the inlined) foo_choose(): Load the foo1 address into the register first, and then perform a `cmove` instruction that overwrites the return register with `&foo2` only if the previous test of the rand value was indicating it. Moving twice 50% of the time is faster than jumping 50% of the time (I assume that `cmove` isn't prohibitively slow).

Comment: Btw, to get shorter assembly you may want to declare `foo_choose` (both the pointer and the function) static so that the optimizing compilers which inline it don't have to emit code for them, *additionally,* because someone might, at some point, decide to call them from another TU.

Comment: I looked at several architectures, including arm64, they all do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Your tests simply do not test anything

Comment: @0___________ Well - you haven't said anything with your comment.

Comment: @MrUser I said!! I will explain: your test method does not test anything.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. `rand` [under linux/glibc, at least] is *expensive*. It calls `random` (See `man 3 random`).
2. The execution time will far exceed the execution time of your dispatch and `foo*` functions.
3. Better to use a simple/fast RNG: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator
4. By having separate programs, when you do `srand(time(&t))` you are getting *different* sequences of random numbers.
5. Because of variations in OS scheduling/timeslicing, it is helpful to do multiple runs of the same test and take the *minimum* time.
6. The execution time is short enough so that using hires (nanosecond) timing can help.

---

Here is a rework of your test programs into a single program:

```
// dotest.c -- dynamic dispatch test

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TEST_N 100000000

#define inline_always       static inline __attribute__((always_inline))

static volatile int state = 0;

time_t t = 1;
int xrand_state;

static void
foo1(void)
{
    state = 1;
}

static void
foo2(void)
{
    state = 2;
}

inline_always int
xrand(void)
{
#if STDRAND
    return rand();
#else
    xrand_state = (xrand_state * 1103515245) + 12345;
    return xrand_state;
#endif
}

int
foo_choose_1(void)
{
    if (xrand() % 2 == 0) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}

void
test1(void)
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < TEST_N; i++) {
        switch (foo_choose_1()) {
        case 1:
            foo1();
            break;
        case 2:
            foo2();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void (*foo_choose_2(void)) () {
    if (xrand() % 2 == 0) {
        return foo2;
    }
    return foo1;
}

void
test2(void)
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < TEST_N; i++)
        (foo_choose_2())();
}

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

void
dotest(void (*test)(void),const char *sym)
{
    double tscbest = 90000.0;

    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 5;  ++iter) {
#if STDRAND
        srand(t);
#else
        xrand_state = t;
#endif

        double tscbeg = tscgetf();
        test();
        double tscend = tscgetf();

        tscend -= tscbeg;
        if (tscend < tscbest)
            tscbest = tscend;
    }

    printf("%.9f %s\n",tscbest,sym);
}

int
main(void)
{

#if SEED
    time(&t);
#endif

    dotest(test1,"test1");
    dotest(test2,"test2");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is `perl` script that tests all combinations of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# runall -- run all tests

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    foreach $stdrand (1,0) {
        foreach $noinl (1,0) {
            foreach $cc ("gcc","clang") {
                dotest();
            }
        }
    }
}

sub dotest
{
    my(@fnoinline);
    my(@cc);

    push(@cc,"-DSTDRAND=$stdrand");

    if ($noinl) {
        if ($cc eq "gcc") {
            push(@cc,"-fno-inline-small-functions");
            push(@cc,"-fno-inline-functions-called-once");
        }
        push(@cc,"-fno-inline-functions");
    }

    printf("\n");
    doexec($cc,"-O2","-o","dotest","dotest.c",@cc);
    doexec("./dotest");
}

sub doexec
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($cmd);
    my($code);

    msgv("doexec: EXEC",@argv);
    $cmd = join(" ",@argv);

    system($cmd);
    $code = $? >> 8;
    exit($code) if ($code);
}

sub msgv
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($totlen);
    my($curlen);
    my($sep);

    foreach $str (@argv) {
        $curlen = length($str) + 1;

        if (($totlen + $curlen) > 78) {
            print("\n");
            $totlen = 0;
        }

        print(" ")
            if ($sep);
        $sep = 1;

        print($str);
        $totlen += $curlen;
    }

    print("\n")
        if ($totlen > 0)
}
```

---

Here is the output of the script:

```
doexec: EXEC gcc -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=1
 -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-inline-functions-called-once
 -fno-inline-functions
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
1.971694409 test1
1.895546644 test2

doexec: EXEC clang -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=1 -fno-inline-functions
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
2.005824467 test1
1.930640078 test2

doexec: EXEC gcc -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=1
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
1.608372519 test1
1.752407737 test2

doexec: EXEC clang -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=1
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
1.249583558 test1
1.770974409 test2

doexec: EXEC gcc -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=0
 -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-inline-functions-called-once
 -fno-inline-functions
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
0.417573279 test1
0.382258426 test2

doexec: EXEC clang -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=0 -fno-inline-functions
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
0.417578010 test1
0.417172264 test2

doexec: EXEC gcc -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=0
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
0.138614488 test1
0.283262261 test2

doexec: EXEC clang -O2 -o dotest dotest.c -DSTDRAND=0
doexec: EXEC ./dotest
0.150371041 test1
0.320875299 test2
```

---

For a more thorough example of generic, switch vs vtable, etc. in C, see my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650)

Comment: Great test! It looks to me that test1 is marginally faster than test2 on average. Can we say that one is better than the other, or they are similar, in terms of performance, on average, in most cases?

Comment: Of course the function pointer method is the classic approach to vtables and certainly the easiest approach. I am trying to figure out how much overhead does these function pointers have. I am thinking about the efficiency something like a function closure.

Comment: For example, how much more does a "function closure" struct cost more than just calling a function.

Comment: I'm not sure what "function closure struct" is. At a guess, see my answer: [Problem with custom written compare function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132252/5382650) and the `minmax` struct. That is, it holds whatever function scoped variables are needed to implement a closure or lambda function (even with langs that support lambdas, under the hood we need something like it)

Comment: To explain, I do mean something like lambda, and I mean something like `struct {char* arg, int (*func(char*, char*))}` so we remember one argument in the struct, so that we just need to supply one other argument to call the function, like std::bind in C++.

Comment: The `minmax` struct does not seem to be linked to a function pointer, so why is it a form of lambda?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there should be much difference between C and C++ in this regard.

The possibility that dynamic dispatch is slower is understandable since it cannot inline the called function which means cannot be optimized that much and it's an additional indirection.
Choosing (different) random numbers might not be a good idea for testing. The different number sequences might affect the results (and I don't know how deterministic the rand() function's cost is). You could pre-calculate the random number sequence.

I think, you shouldn't worry much about choosing one solution over the other when it's not in a tight loop and the called function is not too short. Shorter functions should be inlineable if you want performance.

There's another concerning factor which in a lot of cases might be more important: branch prediction.
Failed prediction is costly. If you branch in a predictable way e.g. 1000 times to foo1 then 1000 times to foo2 then the predictions are almost always successful. There might be other patterns that the branch predictor might recognize. (cppcon, Fedor Pikus: Branchless programming)
This is why it might be better for example in C++ if you order/group the polymorphic elements in an array/vector based on their concrete types so when you iterate over the array and call virtual functions on the objects the predictions are much more likely to be successful.

So measure it but try to use the same numbers for the two tests (random or not).